# Laravel - Sum price for specific method of payment selected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm currently working on some project that needs price summing for each method of payment selected. I did total price sum but I need split sum for every method of payment that is selected during creation

So this is code for sum total price in my home blade

```html
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th>UKUPAN IZNOS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->sum('cijena') }}&euro;</th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

And this is my code for choosing method of payment during creation

```html
<div class="column">
  <label for="placanje">Placanje:</label>
  </br>
  <select 
    class="form-control"
    id="soflow"
    name="placanje"
  >
    <option value="Kartica">Kartica</option>
    <option value="Gotovina">Gotovina</option>
    <option value="Virman">Virman</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you probably need to display them separately, you can do it like this:

```
Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->sum('cijena');
```

and do the same for each option.